# How to tell Git that settings.html is text, not binary

Tags: git

Win7, git 1.8.3.1 (from git-scm.org).

I have a settings.html file that git thinks is binary.  When I do a diff between branches, I see:

```
[master]> git diff master work2
diff --git a/settings.html b/settings.html
index 2e46976..620dff4 100644
Binary files a/settings.html and b/settings.html differ
```

I have tried saving, committing, and pushing settings.html as

> - Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) -- Codepage 65001
> - UTF-8, no signature
> - US-ASCII codepage 20127

No joy; git thinks this one html file is binary.
How can I get git to treat this -- and all html files -- as text?
(I suspect VS2012 is muddying the waters, but the other html/css/js files in the project are treated as text.)

Thanks for any insight...

Comment: Why not try [googling it first](http://www.google.com/search?q=How%20to%20tell%20Git%20that%20file%20is%20text%2C%20not%20binary&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)?

Answer (score 6):

Add the following to a file called `.gitattributes` in the root of your repo:

```
*.html text
```

See [gitattributes(5)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) for more information.

Comment: I believe 'text' in .git attributes affects line endings.  When I made the change, and changing my file's encoding to UTF-8, I got the message: "git diff
fatal: CRLF would be replaced by LF in settings.html."  I have this set: "core.autocrlf=false".  Changing autocrlf seems to have resolved this.